# Edit SharedPreferences tags in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm making an app that takes both a query and a tag. Each time someone presses the save button it creates a new button titled with the tag containing the query. There's an option to edit the query and save it.

Each time I try to edit the button's name I get a new button instead of changing the name. I'm using SharedPreferences to store this information and I'm trying to edit it but I'm still unsure if it contains the exact information like an array so I can update the GUI.
I feel that I'm missing something obvious but I just can't put my finger on it.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //contain the user's saved feeds
    private var savedFeeds: SharedPreferences? = null
    var tagName:String = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        savedFeeds = this.getSharedPreferences("feeds", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        //register listeners for the Save and Clear Tags buttons
        saveButton.setOnClickListener{handleSaveButtonClick()}
        clearTagsButton.setOnClickListener{handleClearTagsButtonClick()}
Log.d("tag", "logging")
        //add previously saved feeds to the GUI
        refreshButtons(null)
    }

    fun copyTag (tag:String): String {
        tagName = tag
        Log.d("TAGClass",tagName)
        return tagName
    }
    //recreate search tag and edit buttons for all saved feeds
    //pass null to create all of them
    private fun refreshButtons(newTag:String?) {
        //store the saved tags in the tags array
        val tags: Array<String> = savedFeeds!!.all.keys.toTypedArray()
        tags.sortWith(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) //sort by tag
        //if a new tag is being added, insert into the GUI at the appropriate location
        if (newTag != null && newTag != tagName) {
            var index = tags.binarySearch(newTag!!)
            if (index < 0) index = -index-1
            makeTagGUI(newTag!!, index)
        }
        else{
            //display all feeds
            for (index in tags.indices)
                makeTagGUI(tags[index],index)
        }
    }

    //add a new search to the saved feeds, then refresh all the button
    private fun makeTag(query:String, tag:String) {
        //original query will be "" if we have a new search
        //getString looks up the previous value associated with tag if any
        //if no value is found, the second arg is returned
        val originalQuery = savedFeeds!!.getString(tag,"")

        //get a SharedPreferences.Editor so we can store the new tag/query or
        //the updated one
        val editor = savedFeeds!!.edit()
        editor.putString(tag, query)
        editor.apply() //store the preferences - updates the file



        //or
        //savedFeeds!!.edit().putString(tag,query).apply()

        //if new query add to GUI
        if (originalQuery == "") {
            refreshButtons(tag)
        }

    } //makeTag

    //add a new button and corresponding edit button to the GUI
    private fun makeTagGUI(tag:String, index: Int) {
        //inflate new_tag_view layout
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
        val newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tag_view,null,false)

        //get newTagButton and set its text and register listener
        val newTagButton = newTagView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.newTagButton)
        newTagButton.text = tag


        newTagButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                handleQueryButtonClicked(v!! as Button)
            }
        })

        //get newTagButton and set its text and register listener
        val newEditButton = newTagView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.newEditButton)
        newEditButton.setText(R.string.edit)
        newEditButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                handleEditButtonClicked(v!! as Button)
                //val tagValue = copyTag(tag)
                Log.d("Buttontag", tagName)
            }
        })

        //add them to the layout
        queryLinearLayout.addView(newTagView,index)


    } //maketaggui

    //remove all the saved searches
    private fun clearButtons() {
        queryLinearLayout.removeAllViews()
    }

    //for save button clicks
    private fun handleSaveButtonClick() {
        //create a tag if both the queryEditText and tagEditText are not empty
        if (queryEditText.text.length > 0 &&
                tagEditText.text.length > 0 ) {

            makeTag(queryEditText.text.toString(),
                    tagEditText.text.toString())
            //val copiedTag = copyTag(tagEditText.text.toString())
            Log.d("TAGGED", tagName + "saveButtonClick")

            //clear text
            queryEditText.setText("")
            tagEditText.setText("")

            //dismiss the keyboard
            (getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as
                    InputMethodManager).hideSoftInputFromWindow(tagEditText.windowToken,0)

        }
        else if (queryEditText.text.length < 0 &&
                tagEditText.text.toString() == tagName)
        {

        }
        else {
            //display a message
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
            builder.setTitle(R.string.missingTitle) //title bar

            //ok button to dismiss the alert
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK,null)

            builder.setMessage(R.string.missingMessage) //message

            //create the dialog
            val errorDialog:AlertDialog = builder.create()
            errorDialog.show()

        }
    }

    //for each of the tag buttons, open a browser to view the feed
    private fun handleQueryButtonClicked(v: Button) {

        //get query
        val buttonText = v.text.toString()
        //val copiedTag = copyTag(v.text.toString())
        Log.d("TAG", tagName + "handleQuery")
        val query = savedFeeds!!.getString(buttonText,"")

        //create the url
        val urlString = getString(R.string.searchURL)+query
        Log.d("TAG",urlString)

        //create an intent to launch a browser
        val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(urlString))

        startActivity(webIntent) //execute the intent
    }

    //handle edit button
    private fun handleEditButtonClicked(v: Button) {
        //get all necessary GUI components
        val buttonRow = v.parent as ConstraintLayout
        val searchButton = buttonRow.findViewById<Button>(R.id.newTagButton)
        val tag = searchButton.text.toString()

        val copiedTag = copyTag(tag)
        Log.d("TAG", tagName + "handleEdit")


        //set the edittexts to match the chosen tag and query
        tagEditText.setText(tag)
        queryEditText.setText(savedFeeds!!.getString(tag,""))
    }

    //handle the clear button
    private fun handleClearTagsButtonClick() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle)

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.erase) { dialog, which ->
            clearButtons()
            savedFeeds!!.edit().clear().apply()
        }

        builder.setCancelable(true)
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null)

        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage)

        builder.create().show()
    }

} //class
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/queryEditText"
            android:hint="@string/queryPrompt" android:imeOptions="actionNext" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/tagEditText"
            android:hint="@string/tagPrompt" android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/queryEditText"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/saveButton" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp" app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tagEditText"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/queryEditText"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/clearTags"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clearTagsButton" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tagEditText" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/clearTagsButton" android:background="@color/light_orange">
        <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/queryLinearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

new_tagview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/newTagRow"
                                                   android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/newTagButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/newEditButton"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/newEditButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/newTagButton" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was that you can't call refreshButtons(null) right in the current constraint layout.

You have to add and remove things from SharedPreferences using .remove and update the current GUI.

Answer (score 0):

changes this code

```
private var savedFeeds: SharedPreferences? = null
```

to

```
private val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contex)
```